# Is there a way to avoid eval in this block of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eval

Is there a way to avoid eval in this block of js?

```
// Check requirements Prototype and Scriptaculous
(function () {
 var requires = [
  'Prototype'
  , 'Scriptaculous'
 ]
 while (r = requires.pop()) {
  if (eval('typeof ' + r + ' == "undefined"')) alert(r + ' is required');
 }
} ());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eval` here is completely pointless:

```
// since everything in the global scope gets defined on 'window'
typeof window[r] === 'undefined';
```

This will do the **exact** same thing, also note that `r` leaks into the global scope.

```
// Check requirements Prototype and Scriptaculous
(function () {
    var requires = ['Prototype', 'Scriptaculous'];

   var r = ''; // make sure to __not__ override a global r
   while (r = requires.pop()) {
       if (typeof window[r] === 'undefined') {
           alert(r + ' is required');
       }
   }
} ());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (typeof window[r] == "undefined")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (r = requires.pop()) {
  if (typeof window[r] == "undefined") alert(r + ' is required');
 }
```